# Configuring oAuth with ADFS windows 2012

Tags: oauth, adfs

I have installed ADFS on windwos 2012. Now I want to authneitcate users using ADFS what type of condifuration needed in ADFS so that my user on the Active Directory on the same machine can be used for authentication. Is there any sepcific configuraiton needed for oAuth and also i need a sample of oauth to work with ADFS. Please help me to sort this?

Many thanks
IK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a claims-enabled application using WIF.

Out the box that will use ADFS which authenticates with AD under the hood.

ADFS 2012 doesn't support OAuth. However, I have read that this has been added to ADFS 2012 R2.

Comment: Thansk. I will upgrade to widnows 2012 R2 because moving forward I will use the oAuth. Does WIF support oAuth?

Comment: I doubt it because it's a different protocol. Refer http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/07/10/extending-device-support-in-active-directory.aspx

Comment: Thanks you. I also need some help how to configure SSO on ADFS so that my oAuth .NEt client can get oauth token and aouthorization to get single sing on capabilities

Comment: Good question. I don't know of any articles that reference the browser flow. I imagine you would use ADAL and there is documentation for a Web API (http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/). Also I don't think this provides SSO.

Comment: I am really sicked off with Windows 2012 R2 ADFS becasue i did not get any information how to configure it for oAuth. Please let me know if there is any information available.

Comment: I did find this article - http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/07/30/securing-a-web-api-with-windows-server-2012-r2-adfs-and-katana/. The key point is "The screen offers WS-Federation and SAML P: we don’t need either of those, and the OAuth2 endpoints are automatically enabled". Vittorio refers to AAL which these days is referred to as ADAL.

Comment: Updated: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/

Comment: Yes I also find that but there are also issue with this now I posted the issue on folloiwng links http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/af64c725-6f27-421b-ba00-1b8a7e02173a/adfs-2012-r2-client-id-registeration-required-for-each-client?forum=Geneva#1a7b77ab-19ef-4e44-8779-daa690453d15

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cfb798b7-02be-4741-b03d-1ce3201bdd50/does-adfs-2012-r2-completely-support-oauth-20-flows?forum=Geneva#c4e234ba-c0dc-4708-bed3-dac30104c31a

http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/484022